# Building a script that changes cells' colour when clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, mobile, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need a function on Google Sheets that changes the colour of a cell in a spreadsheet when the specific cell is clicked. It needs to cycle through four predefined colours.

I also need this function from mobile devices, or at least the iPad.

Comment: Because just clicking on a cell is not an edit, there is no trigger for this. onEdit, however, will run automatically on mobile devices after an edit is finished.

Comment: If  clicking cells can't trigger anything, maybe cells can be made into dropdowns where I can select one out of four colours? I've seen a guide on how to make a cell into a dropdown in google spreadsheets, but the dropdown only had two states (nothing and a predefined text), also, that didn't work on the ipad.

Comment: Do you actually need the function to operate on the spreadsheet (which will not work as Frederic says) or will a view of the spreadsheet table do? If *all* you are doing is clicking a cell then a scripted UI with a grid will do the job.

Comment: add a vote to [issue 237](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=237) on the issue and feature request tracker.

Comment: @DavidF I only need the spreadsheet for checking off students when they come to and leave activities, so I guess a grid will do if I can click specific cells to change their colours.

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Validation to create a a drop down list and only allow input from that list.  Then use conditional formatting to make each of the four menu items change the background color of the cell.

Go to your spreadsheet and make sure the cell that you want is selected. On the menu bar, go to Date>Validation.  Change Criteria to "Items from a list."  Enter list items "red,green,blue,orange".  Check "show list of items in a drop-down menu".  Uncheck "allow invalid data, but show warning."  Save the changes, and with the cell still selected, go on the menubar to Formatting>Conditional Formatting.  Use the text contains criteria like this...
'Text contains' "{you would type here, let's say red}" then put a check mark next to Background and then in the final box select the color that you would want the cell to change to (in this case, red).  You can add more lines to this conditional formatting (ie -- so do this last part over again for green and blue and orange).

Comment: You can even use conditional formatting to have it be a white BG if the cell is blank.  Also, you could change the text color to match the BG color, so it looks like there's nothing in the cell except for the BG color.

Comment: Not at a place I can test this right now, but it sounds super! One question though: will these dropdowns work on am ipad? I've tried something similar once and those dropdowns didnt show up on an ipad

Comment: This worked quite well on a computer, but not on the ipad. Dropdowns won't work. Which brings me to another question: can I somehow add checkboxes and conditionally format cells depending on which boxes are checked?

Comment: Yeah, the data validation dropdowns don't work on mobile devices. You can add drawings and assign a script for when they're clicked, but I don't know if they will work in the mobile apps.

Comment: If you wanted to keep it simple, you could still do data validation, but not use a drop-down list, but still not allow invalid data. Just change the color names to 1,2,3,4 and change your conditional formatting terms as well.  It adds a click, but would probably still be pretty fast, and I think you could even have a data validation pop-up box that would give the user a hint about what they were entering (ie, 1 = Student arrived, 2 = Student arrived late, 3 = Student never arrived, 4 = student canceled).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a UI app that reflects the values in a spreadsheet. The grid and widgets have default size. The underlying data is assumed values 0 -3. In example the spreadsheet is not updated - for a practical implementation you would need to use locking if concurrent updating is required. This works as expected on an ipad.

```
function doGet() {
    var colours = ["white","green","blue","red"];  // background colour names referenced by offset 0,1,2,3
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var grid = app.createFlexTable();  // the grid for ui
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('your spreadsheet id here')      ;  // your spreadsheet
    var data = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();  // all the data on sheet 0  (valid values correspond to colour offset)
    var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');  
    // fill the grid with text widgets, all using same clickhandler, set colour according to current data value of cell, Tag carries value to server handler
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      for (j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
        var widget = app.createTextBox().setText(data[i][j]).addClickHandler(handler).setId("CellR"+i+"C"+j).setTag(data[i][j]).setStyleAttribute("background-color", colours[data[i][j]]);
        grid.setWidget(i, j, widget);
      }
    }
    app.add(grid);
    return app;
    // need to update the spreadsheet to match tag values before closing app!
    }

  function myClickHandler(e) {
    var colours = ["white","green","blue","red"];
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var colourvalue = parseInt(e.parameter[e.parameter.source+"_tag"] )+ 1; // gets the current tag value of clicked widget and increments it
    if (colourvalue > 3) {
      colourvalue = 0;   // reset at 4
    };
    // update the widget
    app.getElementById(e.parameter.source).setStyleAttribute("background-color", colours[colourvalue]).setText(colourvalue).setTag(colourvalue);
    return app;
  }
```